# Prevent content from overflowing horizontally

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In [this codepen Vuetify demo](https://codepen.io/domurtag147/pen/GREqrGW?editors=1010), I'm using a two column layout. The first column has a `<v-list>` inside a green `<v-alert>`. If you click the "toggle text" button, the title of the first item in the list toggles between short and long.

When the text is long, it overflows the `<v-alert>` and runs into the adjacent column

[image]

How can I prevent this? I would ideally like the text to be truncated with ellipsis once it reaches the edge of the green `<v-alert>` or if that is not possible, for the text to wrap over multiple lines within the alert.

I've tried adding the following class to the text, but it doesn't prevent the overflow

```
.prevent-overflow {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: You need a max width for you overflow properties to work, try first with fixed width and check if your overflow properties are working or not then replace fixed widths with relative/responsive widths

Comment: Answering the second part "for the text to wrap over multiple lines within the alert" add these to your ```.prevent-overflow``` class ```word-wrap: break-word;``` ```white-space: pre-wrap``` and ```word-break: break-word;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to not over flow the green container, you need to set the overflow there.

```
          <v-alert text color="success" class="prevent-overflow">
```

will be where you aim.
Just to be clear, overflow sets on the contained items, when you set an over flow to your `div`, what you mean is - I want whats inside of this `div` to act like this if it goes beyond it.

For the ellipsis you will need to set 2 things, 1 is on the title add `text-over: ellipsis`, no need in word wrap and all, it will just cause the text to go down, unless thats what you want.
Second thing is to set `width` to the div that holds the text directly.

In your case for a quick fix you can do for example:

```
.v-list-item__title {
  width: 20px;
}
.prevent-overflow2 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated the demo with your suggestion, and the text doesn't overflow now, but the ellipsis aren't added to the end of the truncated text